# Unable to perform Uber login programmatically

Tags: java, android, authentication, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I am trying to integrate my app using Uber SDK and I followed their instructions.

- Registered my app in their developer dashboard with app signature, Client Id, Client Signature and Redirect URI
- Instantiated their LoginManager class and am calling the login method.

When I run the app in simulator in Android studio, it gets stuck at:
https://login.uber.com

When I run it on my actual device, I get the error from Uber:
Unable to Connect
and it asks me to try again later.

My code snippet leading to log in:

```
SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
    // This is necessary
    .setClientId("removed for sharing")
    .setClientSecret("removed for sharing")
    // This is necessary if you'll be using implicit grant
    .setRedirectUri("removed for sharing")
    // Your scopes for authentication here      
    .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS))
    .build();

UberSdk.initialize(config);

LoginCallback loginCallback = new LoginCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLoginCancel() {
        // User canceled login
        System.out.println("User Cancelled login");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginError(@NonNull AuthenticationError error) {
        // Error occurred during login
        System.out.println("User login error");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(@NonNull AccessToken accessToken) {
        // Successful login! The AccessToken will have already been saved.
        System.out.println("Login success!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthorizationCodeReceived(@NonNull String authCode) {
        System.out.println("Auth code received");
    }
};

AccessTokenStorage accessTokenStorage = new AccessTokenManager(this);
loginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenStorage, loginCallback);

loginManager.login(this);
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to share your ClientId and ClientSecret on some public forum?

Comment: luk2302, Thanks for pointing. It is just a test app. In any case, removed the relevant portion.